Placement on the Element Plus date picker placement not working
Placement on the Element Plus date picker in my vue project opening on the right even though placement is set as bottom. I am setting both :popper-options and placement but it is still opening on the right.
My code:
<el-date-picker
        v-model="dateRange"
        type="daterange"
        unlink-panels="false"
        range-separator="-"
        format="MMM DD, YYYY"
        value-format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        :start-placeholder="formattedStartDate"
        :end-placeholder="formattedEndDate"
        :shortcuts="shortcuts"
        :popper-options="popperOptions"
        placement="bottom-start"      
/>

data() {
popperOptions: {
        placement: "bottom-start",
      },
}

How do I adjust the placement of the date picker to open at bottom-start?
